# Can you use two dummy variables?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, categorical-encoding

Is it possible to use two dummy variables for breakpoints in a linear regression? In EViews I've created the following:

ls log(consumption) c log(gdp) log(gdp(-1)) log(consumption(-1)) @year>1989 @year>2008

The model is regressing household expenditure against GDP in Finland from 1970 to 2014 and the two dummy variables are an attempt to address breakpoints in the 2007/2008 financial crisis and the Finnish banking crisis of the 1990s.

Answer (score 0):

breakpoints can either be in terms of level (i.e.intercepts ) or slopes . If you explicitely post your augmented data ( 3 columns ; n rows ) I will tell you which one your are testing.